# Systematic modifying of lists' elements

Tags: python, list

I am using python. I have lists of coordinates called `segments_init` and I want to translate it into another system as follows:

```
segments_init = [x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, ...]

segments_new = [x1, -z1, 0, x2, -z2, 0, x3, -z3, 0, ...]
```

Note: each `segments_init` list is generated by the software built-in command in a for as follows

```
for i in segments:
    segment_init = ce.getVertices(ce.findByOID(segmentsOID))
```

Comment: And what's your question exactly ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's always a good idea to share what have you tried so far and where you encounter problem.

Comment: Alas, the OP needs to change the sign of the `z`s... otherwise `new, new[1::3],  new[2::3] = old[:], old[2::3], [0]*(len(old)//3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> segments_init = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9] 
>>> list(zip(segments_init[0::3], list(map(lambda x:-x, segments_init[2::3])), [0]*(len(segments_init)//3)))
[(1, -3, 0), (4, -6, 0), (7, -9, 0)]
```

Even though its better to club a single 3d co-ordinate together for better readability but if you want to flatten the list, you can use this:

```
>>> [i for l in list(zip(segments_init[0::3], list(map(lambda x:-x, segments_init[2::3])), [0]*(len(segments_init)//3))) for i in l]
[1, -3, 0, 4, -6, 0, 7, -9, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a one-line list comprehension:

```
>>> segments_init = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>>> [j if i%3 == 0 else -segments_init[i+1] if i%3 == 1 else 0 for i, j in enumerate(segments_init)]
[1, -3, 0, 4, -6, 0, 7, -9, 0]
```

Alternatively, using [extended slicing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy):

```
>>> segments_init = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

>>> segments_new = list(segments_init)
>>> segments_new[1::3] = [-i for i in segments_init[2::3]]
>>> segments_new[2::3] = len(segments_init)//3 * [0]

>>> segments_new
[1, -3, 0, 4, -6, 0, 7, -9, 0]
```